# How can I recalculate the coord of point after (rotate, translate and scale)

Tags: javascript, konvajs, react-konva

There are two stages. Both include hall image. Hall image size is static but two stages dimension is dynamic.

The image which is located in the middle of the stages and there are thousands of polygons on image.

I draw several polygons on the first stage and transform them. then I click save button. then drawn polygons will be rendered on the second stage whose dimension is different. But As I mentioned, they both include hall image. My polygons should be located in the same position in two stages. But  they should respect stage dimensions.

I tried `item.getAbsoluteTransform().point({ x: point[0], y: point[1] })` but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you make online demo of your issue?

Comment: I have a related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76525337 I appreciate if you could help. Thanks